# Срабатывает действие сохранения данных через адаптер лишь для последнего активного элемента

Tags: java, sqlite, listview, adapter, android-sqlite

При Long click`е на один элемент и выходе в предыдущей активности все сохраняется хорошо. Однако, когда Long click делаю на несколько элементов списка, сохраняется лишь последний...

Adapter:

```java
    public View getView(final int index, View v, ViewGroup vg){

        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if(v != null){
            vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }else{
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.plan_line_view, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.tv = v.findViewById(R.id.dataToView);
        }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";BOOL;");
        final String[] item = pattern.split(data[index]);

        if(item[1].equals("true"))
            v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        else
            v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        vh.tv.setText(item[0]);

        v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                boolean bool = item[1].equals("true");

                if(!bool)
                    view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                else
                    view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));


                item[1] = "" + !bool;

               dbHelper.completePlanItem(target, index, !bool);

               return false;
            }
        });
```

From database:

```java
    public void completePlanItem(Plan target, int index, boolean b){
        StringBuilder fDescription = new StringBuilder();
        String temp;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";POINT;");
        String[] dataArr = pattern.split(target.fDescription);

        pattern = Pattern.compile(";BOOL;");
        String[] item = pattern.split(dataArr[index]);
        item[1] = "" + b;

        temp = item[0] + ";BOOL;" + item[1];

        for(int i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++){
            if (i == index){
                fDescription.append(temp + ";POINT;");
            } else {
                fDescription.append(dataArr[i] + ";POINT;");
            }
        }


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("FULL_DESCRIPTION", fDescription.toString());
        db.update("PLANNING", content, "NAME = ? AND SHORT_DESCRIPTION = ?", new String[]{target.name, target.sDescription});
        db.close();
    }
```

Спасибо огромное заранее!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ состоит в том, что последнее изменение в БД не затрагивает предыдущие: После того, как срабатывает изменение в БД для конкретного элемента, мы **НЕ** сохраняем изменения для следующего изменения. Таким образом, следующее изменение перекрывает предыдущее.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/392000)

Comment: Но я и есть автор :)

Comment: Да, я знаю. Это стандартный автоматический комментарий из очереди проверок. Просто не понятно - как ваш ответ решает задачу изложенную в вашем же вопросе. Вам как автору всё понятно, но это не значит, что и другие это также  хорошо поймут.

Comment: Сейчас исправлю..